# fortran array values update automatically

Tags: fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to test the Fortran 2003 feature that allows to add an element to an array. Consider the following code:

```
program test

implicit none
integer :: i
integer, parameter :: n=6, j=2
integer, allocatable :: inx(:)

open(3, file='check.dat')

allocate(inx(0:1)); inx=0

do i=0,1
 write(3,*) i, inx(i)
end do


do i=1,n
 inx=[inx,i+j]
end do

do i=0,n
 write(3,*) i, inx(i)
end do


end program test
```

I get the following runtime error:

```
At line 22 of file test.f90
Fortran runtime error: Index '0' of dimension 1 of array 'inx' below lower bound of 1
```

I explicitly set `inx(0:1)`, so that `inx`'s index starts from zero ( I want `inx(0:some number))` but it seems that's it's reallocating from `1`?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran]. When you use atomatic re-allocation, the array indexing starts from 1. We probably have some duplicate.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава where can I find a tutorial/guide/notes for the latest fortan (2018) version?

Comment: See https://fortran-lang.org